# Не сохраняются сессии

Tags: php, сессия

В общем такой код. По логике, при первой загрузке страницы должно вывестись `empty`, а при последующих `no empty`. Но все время выводится `empty`.

```
session_start();
if(empty($_SESSION['user_id'])){
    echo "empty";
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = "some id";
} else {
    echo "no empty";
}
```

Файл сохранен в кодировке `UTF-8 без BOM`, ошибки все включены и скрипт ошибок не выдает, в папке с сессиями на каждую перезагрузку страницы создается новый файл с сессией (вес показывает 1кб). Если в сессию ничего не писать, то он будет весить 0кб.

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Проверьте приходят-ли куки в браузер. Посмотрите на заголовки, которые возвращает сервер.

Comment: @tutankhamun, в браузер все приходит и устанавливается. А вот отправить на сервер - браузер ничего не отправляет. Что с этим можно сделать?

Comment: Все, разобрался.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Абсолютно рабочий код. Проверьте, есть ли вывод в браузер до `session_start()`. Если этот скрипт вызывается из другого скрипта - начните проверять оттуда.

Еще вариант. Раз каждый раз создается новый файл, значит каждый раз стартует новая сессия. А это значит, что браузер не возвращает переменную сессии. Подробнее можно почитать [здесь](http://phpfaq.ru/sessions)

Либо в `php.ini` неверная настройка сессий. Почитайте по ссылке выше.

Comment: Проблема, как выяснилось, кроется в том, что браузер не отправляет куки с идентификатором сессии. Как ее решить я не знаю.

Answer (score 0):

Взял Ваш код и вставил - все работает, первая загрузка - empty, следующая - no empty, проверяйте Ваши настройки сессии

Answer (score 0):

```
if( empty($_SESSION['user_id']) and empty($_COOKIE['user_id'])){
    echo "empty";
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = "some id";
    setcookie("user_id", "some id");
} else {
    echo "no empty";
}
if( isset($_GET['exit']) ){
    session_destroy();
    setcookie('user_id', null, -1, '/');
    setcookie('user_id', null, -1, '/');
    header('Location: /');
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]